# FIND+PERL: How to add a continuous counter to all cases of a certain tag in directory full of files

Tags: bash, perl, find, counter

I have thousands of XML files and I need to add a continuous incremental counter to each occurrence of a certain tag in all of them. In other words, if there are 10 files and 50 cases of the tag in each, the counter should go from 1 to 500, with 1-50 being in the first file, 51-100 in the second, and so on.

I'm using `find` to get all the files and Perl to do the search and replace operations inside each file. The base code I'm working with is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -name "*.xml" -exec perl -i -p0e "s#<tag>#<tag count=${COUNTER}>#gm" {} +`
```

This should take each occurrence of `<tag>` and add the current counter value, e.g. `<tag counter=000001924>`.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to maintain the counter values between files. If I put `COUNTER=COUNTER+1` before `find`, the counter obviously never increments. If I put it inside the Perl code, it resets to 0 for each file.

And unfortunately, all the answers I can find are for adding a counter number to *filenames* rather than to *something within files*, which is a different problem.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find -exec perl` may launch `perl` any number of times, so that's no good. We need to ensure that only one `perl` process is launched (unless we somehow store the counter somewhere persistent like in a file).

We could have `find` print the file names and read them in `perl`, but there's not much point in doing that when it's just as easy to get the list of file names in Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find::Rule qw( );
use XML::LibXML      qw( );

my $counter = 0;
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();

for my $qfn (
   File::Find::Rule
      ->file
      ->name("*.xml")
      ->in(".")
) {
   eval {
      my $doc = $parser->parse_file($qfn);
      $_->setAttribute("count", ++$counter) for $doc->findnodes("//tag");
      $doc->toFile($qfn, 0);
      return 1;
   }
      or warn("Error processing \"$qfn\": $@\n");
}
```

You  may store that in a file you can simply execute, or you can wrap within `perl -e'...'`.

Comment: Success! There's a small typo in your code -- "Find::File::Rule" should be "File::Find::Rule". Once I changed that, everything worked perfectly! I appreciate your help greatly. I also savored the elegant approach of actually parsing the XML, rather than using a regex, as I had been doing. Quite the lesson!

Comment: Two quick questions: (1) This script inserts `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at the beginning of each file. Is there any way to suppress that? And (2) the script also converts non-ASCII Unicode characters like `ó` into entities such as `&#xF3;`, which may be proper XML, but it is incompatible with the next software these files are processed by. Can this conversion be prevented? I've tried `expand_entities => 0`, `complete_attributes => 0`, `no_defdtd => 1`, and some other settings to no avail.

Comment: @GilWilliams You could try [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) which is less XML-strict: `my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse(read_text $qfn); $dom->find('tag')->each(sub { $_->{count} = ++$counter }); write_text $qfn, $dom->to_string;` (I used File::Slurper for reading and writing the file, you could also use Path::Tiny or Mojo::File but make sure to decode/encode UTF-8 or the proper encoding as Mojo::DOM will not do this.)

Comment: 1) You shouldn't have to do so, but you could print the root element instead. It's a little trickier because it's a silly thing to do. You'll need to encode the output of `$doc->documentElement->toString` and place it in a file. 2) libxml is extra careful when an encoding isn't explicitly specified in the document.  Specifying an encoding (e.g. by adding `$doc->setEncoding("UTF-8");`) will resolve this.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks again for your help! Setting the encoding did the trick!

Comment: With the new code suggested by @ikegami, everything is working, but I have four input files that fail for some reason. They have the same permissions as the files that can be processed, and their sizes are in the same range as other files. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: `Error processing "/file/path/filename": ` with nothing after the colon.

Comment: woops, should be `$@`, not `$!`.

Comment: @ikegami That does indeed do the trick. The errors are `PCDATA invalid Char value 28` and `PCDATA invalid Char value 29`, so it seems I have a handful of problematic characters in the source files.

Comment: Certain characters are not allowed in XML. If you need to transmit binary data, you could encode it (e.g. using base64)